# How can I encrypt my USB Flash Drives and External Hardisk with a secure password?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to encrypt an USB stick?](https://superuser.com/questions/75177/how-to-encrypt-an-usb-stick)

Please tell me some security encryption methods or softwares to encrypt my USB flash drives and External Hard Disks with secure password. Thanks you very much for your kindness.

Comment: Had similar question, see [this](http://superuser.com/questions/281910/password-protect-external-hard-disk-that-works-both-in-windows-and-in-ubuntu/281914#281914)

Answer (score 5):

See [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/), a free open-source disk encryption software for Windows 7/Vista/XP, Mac OS X, and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Truecrypt in portable](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=truecrypt-portable) mode, [Bitlocker to Go](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dd408739) if you have a version of Windows 7 that supports configuring a drive with it or if you want hardware protection you can get something like an  [Ironkey](https://www.ironkey.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I didint know about the TrueCrypt or Bitlocker softwares, but i used to use WinRar and protect the rar file with a password... This dont disable the acess to files, but disable weird people to open your files..... You could use Winrar + Truecrypt for a high level of security.....